# Is there a ttk.Canvas class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Documents/dev/myui/myui.py", line 134, in <module>
    myCanvas = ttk.Canvas(myFrame, width=root.winfo_width(), height=30, borderwidth=1, padding='0 1 0 1', style='myCanvas.TFrame')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Canvas'
```

This tells me there is no such a Canvas class with themed-TK. How do I use canvas with ttk then? Just the same old tk.Canvas?

I'm running native Python 2.7 on Mac OS X El Capitan.

Comment: `Canvas` doesn't need theme so there is no `ttk.Canvas` (they didn't create it). Use `tk.Canvas`.

Comment: Why don't you simply try the tk Canvas and see if it works?

Comment: Thanks @furas , that's what I ended up doing. If you please make your comment an answer, I'll mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no ttk canvas. You can use the `Canvas` widget that is part of Tkinter.